# Can I exclude some specific warnings from "treat warnings as errors" without disabling them?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

In my Visual C++ code I want to have `/WX` - "treat warnings as errors". This makes me deal with each warning, including [C4996](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - "X was declared deprecated" which I don't want to address - I don't want to change code at the moment and I don't want to disable C4996 so that it remains in the output. So ideally I'd like to have something like:

```
#pragma warning( ExcludeFromWX:4996)
```

so that all warnings except this one are treated as errors when `/WX` is used and this warning is just displayed and compilation continues.

Is it possible to get such behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to reset the specified warning by using following pragma. I did not test it though and you did not mention trying this:

**UPDATE**
Changing the warning level should succeed

```
#pragma warning( 4 : 4996 )
```

This does not work:

```
#pragma warning( default : 4996 )
```

Comment: This will not affect `/WX` - this resets the warning level to default one and enables the warning.

Comment: ah ok I just was successful by setting the warning level with #pragma warning(4 : ...), I updated my answer above

Comment: I don't get it. How will that help against `/WX` stopping compilation?

Comment: Even though warnings are regarded as errors they only count as warnings if the warning level is reached. Should you also display warnings with a level of 4 this will not work of course. However this is not usual afaik.

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I don't want to conseal C4996 - I want it to be displayed but not stop compilation.

Comment: pardon, it does supress the output which you explicitly wanted before :( However it is at least possible to recognize the the warning when compiling with a different output level. So you will always have to do two builds: One without /WX and one including it with suppressed warning. I suspect this of not being very useful for daily work, but for automatic builds or analysis it might be an option to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Nope, I don't want to suppress the output - I want the warning to remain in the output. Suppressing the output is trivial.